# Binned of phase-folded light curve

Tags: magnitude, light-curve

How I can bin a magnitude phase-folded lightcurve? I take mean values magnitudes and it's uncertainties but this is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Astronomy Stack Exchange! Can you edit your question to provide a few more details about what exactly it is you tried that was wrong, and what kind of binning you want to achieve?

Comment: Magnitudes are logarithmic, so taking the mean of them is incorrect. You should take the mean flux and then turn it into a magnitude.